# Sort list of two types of object with multiple criteria

Tags: c#, list

I have two objects in the TransactionList as debit & credit

I need to sort TransactionList  in below orders
Date (in ascending order)

Transaction Type (Credits first, then Debits)

Amount (in ascending order)

Description (in ascending order)

This is what I'm trying

```
data.OrderBy(x => x.Date).ThenBy(x => <sort here by credit first>).ThenBy(x => x.Amount).ThenBy(x => x.Description);
```

But this does not seem to work (not able to sort by type of object). Please suggest.

Comment: `typeof(Credit)` is a compile-time constant. Do you mean `x.GetType()` ? Or just `c.DebitType`?

Comment: Try to use:   `data.OrderBy(x => x.Date).ThenBy(x => x.GetType().Name).ThenBy(x => x.Amount).ThenBy(x => x.Description);`

Comment: @IVAAAN123 sorry this is not working

Comment: @Blorgbeard i want to sort by credit first and then debit

Comment: @user3904811 your **credit** class looks like `public class Debit : Transaction`. Maybe you mean `public class Credit : Transaction` ?

Comment: @IVAAAN123 sorry that was a typo, I edited it.

Comment: @user3904811 show me data what you try to sort. My code works fine for me

Comment: @IVAAAN123 answer below works, but how do I cast result to TransactionList?

Comment: @user3904811 `TransactionList list = new TransactionList(sortresult.ToList());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
var result = data.OrderBy( x => x.Date ).ThenBy( x => x.GetType().ToString() ).ThenBy( x => x.Amount ).ThenBy( x => x.Description );
```